# Does Chart.js API supports real time pie charts?

Tags: pie-chart

My web page specifies CPU usage in percentage which gets updated every 10 seconds. So can the pie chart of Chart.js API be used to show the real time content?

In general, will the Pie chart of Chart.js API support real time or dynamic behavior ?

Answer (score 1):

I've never used Chart.js, but you should be able re-render the chart as needed (looking at the [Chart.js docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/), via `.update()`). E.g. update the chart every 10 seconds.

You could use [Socket.IO](http://socket.io) or a similar tool for the 'real-time' aspect of your app. Or you could just simply poll for updates via AJAX.